# Kubernetes Open Policy Agent (OPA) If Else

Tags: kubernetes, open-policy-agent, rego

I'm trying to implement an if else clause in a mutate rule like so ...

```
a := {
 "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path": "/healthz",
"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports": `[{"HTTPS": 443}]`
}

b := {
  "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type": "ip",
   "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy": "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
}

annotations := merge_objects(a,b) {
   kinds[input.request.object.kind] == "Ingress"
}
```

What is the proper syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want annotations to be empty unless the kind matches `Ingress` you could do something like this, using `else`:

```
a := {
    "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path": "/healthz",
    "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports": `[{"HTTPS": 443}]`
}

b := {
    "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type": "ip",
    "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy": "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
}

annotations = object.union(a, b) {
    kinds[input.request.object.kind] == "Ingress"
} else = {}
```

More idomatic Rego would probably be to use a default value for `annotations` though:

```
default annotations = {}

annotations = object.union(a, b) {
    kinds[input.request.object.kind] == "Ingress"
}
```